# Struts2 return json if authentication failed in interceptor

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2

Please Note, I am not a Java developer so my question may have some heart breaking assumptions & invalid piece of code.

I have an interceptor which takes care of login authentication.

```
<global-results>
   <result name="login">/admin/login.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

As shown, it redirects to login.jsp when authentication fails i.e. the return value is "login" (in this case)

What I want to achieve is, I return some other value (say "loginAjax") and it should not send an HTTP 302, instead it should return back a JSON response.

I don't know if that possible at all or not. I have this other piece in struts.xml which returns json when a particular value is returned from Action.

```
<result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties">
        return_id, return_message
    </param>
</result>
```

I don't know how should I tie both the pieces together and get it working for the same interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global result is not tied to one or more Interceptors or Actions: it is global to everyone, so it will be rendered when returned, no matter who is returning it.

You need to add a global (keeping it consistent with your other login result, that is global) result of type json, like this:

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="login">/admin/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="loginAjax" type="json" />
</global-results>
```

Then, you can send a particular statusCode, or errorCode, [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17235529/1654265).

If you need to understand what kind of result you should return from *within* the Interceptor, you should proceed like described [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691162/1654265), by checking the type of the result that it would be returned in case of success.

<sub>P.S: Oh, and consider hiring a Java dev to do Java stuff properly :)</sub>

Comment: Thanks man for your help. I will try your solution. And your advice too :P