# Accessing struts action result's parameters in an interceptor

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2

I'm using struts and spring integrated frameworks in my project. I have an interceptor before every struts action call. I need to access my action name and am doing so with the following piece of code:

```
actionInvocation.getProxy().getActionName();
```

and my struts action in struts.xml is :

```
<action name="uploadDocument" class="commonAction" method="uploadDocument">
  <interceptor-ref name="sessionStack"/><interceptor-ref name="cachingStack"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
    <param name="result">inputStream</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

I need to access the parameters under the result tag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

You can read the result configuration in a ResultConfig object, [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691162/1654265), that will expose a Map of its params, like shown by [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.16.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/ResultConfig.java#ResultConfig).

Something like:

```
// Get the action configuration defined in struts.xml
ActionConfig config = invocation.getProxy().getConfig(); 

// Get the SUCCESS result configured for that Action
ResultConfig success = config.getResults().get("success");

// Iterate the Params, friendly printing :)
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : success.getParams().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("<param name=\"" 
                       + entry.getKey() 
                       + "\">"
                       + entry.getValue()
                       + "</param>");
}
```

Comment: `success` == `Action.SUCCESS`.

Comment: ?? `config.getResults().get(Action.SUCCESS)` is better. :)

Comment: You are right. And syntactically fetish :D but isn't "success" showing cleaner that you can put a custom string to target a custom result ?