# Struts2 interceptor for ajax requests

Tags: ajax, json, struts2, interceptor

Application has two packages one for jsp (struts.xml) and another for json results (struts-json.xml) . Actions in both packages share the same interceptors. When interceptor interrupts and returns error then for ajax request I want to return serialized json object back. Object has error code and description. 
To achieve that I redirected to another method :

```
<result name="errorFromInterceptor" type="redirectAction">
```

Is there a better way to populate and return object when request is captured by interceptor?

Comment: It's unclear how you did a redirect, and unknown if it worked or not.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear, but I guess reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16691162/1654265) might worth a minute

Comment: when global error triggered by interceptor I want to forward to action that would populate object with proper message for json response.

Comment: What do you mean by better way? What is not working?